# Transform query result from a request to an object with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an User table in my database.

Structure of tabUser : intID , strUsername, strPassword

In my User class I want to list all the users that my database contains.

What I tried  :

```
 public List<User> GetAllUsers()
     using (var db = new AdventureWorksEntities())
           {
              return (from u in db.tabUser
                       select new User{
                          u.strUsername
                      }).ToList();
            }
```

User constructor :

```
public class User {

        private strUsername;

        public User() {}

        public User(string username){
            this.strUsername = username;
        }

        public void setUsername(string username){
            this.strUsername = username;
        }

        public string getUsername(){

            return strUsername;
        }
```

I want that the method return a list of all of my users.
But this does not work. Any help please ?

Comment: Why don't you use properties, are you only familiar with java? Apart from that, what is the problem with your code? Why don't you use the constructor that takes the `username`?

Comment: db.tabUser.Select(x => new User (x.strUsername)).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the constructor that takes the `username`?

```
return db.tabUser.Select(u => new User(u.strUsername)).ToList();
```

**Update**: According to the comments it seems to be a *must-have* to have a parameterless constructor and to use property initializers with Linq-To-Entities. The rest still applies:

Why don't you use [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)? Then you could use your code. Currently it doesn't work because you are **trying to access the private field** `strUsername`.

```
public class User
{
    public User() {}
    public User(string username)
    {
        this.UserName = username;
    }
    public string UserName { get; set; }    
}
```

Now your code works(fixed the [naming/capitalization convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) issue):

```
return (from u in db.tabUser
        select new User{ u.Username = u.strUsername })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure Linq-to-Entities supports projection with non parameter-less constructor

Comment: OP seems to be using EF. If so, using a parameterless constructor and property initializers in a must.

Comment: Yes, I got an error when I tried your solution. Linq does not support that

Comment: @joohn: added the parameterless constructor.The core of my answer still applies. You can't access the private field, use the property.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked but I needed to apply one change. 
  return (from u in db.tabUser
                    select new User {strUsername=  u.strUsername })
        .ToList();